# Require fields in FormData using TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I want to have `FormData` ([documentation](https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-JavaScript/interfaces/_node_modules_typedoc_node_modules_typescript_lib_lib_dom_d_.formdata.html#get)) interface with specified required fields. So I want to use TypeScript to check if my formData has all required fields.

```
export interface AddRequest {
  image: Blob;
  username: string;
}

// This is invalid
export interface AddRequestApi extends FormData {
  image: FormDataEntryValue;
  username: FormDataEntryValue;
}
```

so I can do:

```
export const mapRequest = (request: AddRequest): AddRequestApi => {
  const { image, username } = request;

  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('image', image);
  formData.append('username', username);

  // I want my ts compiler to check if returned formData has required fields
  // that should be stated in AddRequestApi type (or interface)
  return formData;
};
```

Comment: put a simple question at the bottom

Comment: Typescript's type checking does not work at runtime, so you can't use a typescript interface to check if someone is posting the correct data. You still have to use `if` statements to see if some data is there and what type it is.

Comment: The approach of multiple `.append()` calls means the code can only be checked at runtime, not compile time (this means TS can't check it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Fabian Lauer said:

> The approach of multiple .append() calls means the code can only be checked at runtime, not compile time (this means TS can't check it)

Now, there are some ways runtime type-check can be achieved with TS.

Check out this blog
https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-we-use-our-typescript-type-information-at-runtime-6e95b801cfeb

> Validation — using another equally as awesome tool, Another JSON Schema Validator or ajv, we can validate any object at runtime simply by passing in the object and our schema. We’ll even get error outputs in a format that we can use programmatically for things such as showing errors on a form against the field that is invalid, automatically fixing invalid properties, etc.

Answer (score 4):

Something like this?

```js
type MyFormFields = "image" | "username";

interface MyFormData extends FormData {
    append(name: MyFormFields, value: string | Blob, fileName?: string): void
}


function bar(data: MyFormData) {
    const image = new Blob();
    const username = "myusername";
    data.append("image", image)
    data.append("username", username);
    data.append("something", "not working"); 
                // Argument of type '"something"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'MyFormFields'.
}
```

Interface of `FormData.append()` is

```js
append(name: string, value: string | Blob, fileName?: string): void
```

So try limiting name paramter only to your custom required fields when you override interface of append function.